# How to convert the Mean Average Precision into an error metric?

Tags: mean, error

I am interested in taking the mean average precision metric which is primarily a performance metric (high is good, low is bad) into an error metric (high is bad, low is good). Because mean average precision is between 0 and 100 can I simply take 100 - mAP? If not why can this not be done, and if so then what would the resulting metric be called?